# What's faster: anchoring or hide/show with JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, performance

I'm making a website for a client that will mostly be used offline through a wifi router. But there will also be an online version available. The purpose of this is to distribute files in parts of the world where infrastructure is not suitable for internet access. For those who do have internet access in some of these parts, the internet probably isn't very fast or reliable.

Some of the pages I've made can be accessed simply by using JS functions to hide one page and show another, instead of anchoring to another file. I figured this method might load content quicker, rather than linking to multiple pages. But is that true? Or should I just put all the content on separate pages?

Comment: Best way to tell for sure is to try a sample of both then test/measure and compare.

Comment: @scunliffe I'm not really sure how to make a controlled environment for this test. My internet connection is probably many times faster than the locations where this site will be used.

Comment: @Chris_topher: Well, do you still have one of those old AOL CDs...?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I think they JUST discontinued that. Oh well...

Comment: In any environment, this will be debatable. With slow internet, it might make sense to have a lot of separate pages so that nobody has to download a larger file. They can get the page they need to get the information and not load the rest. But if people are going to need to access most/all of the information, then it makes more sense to have it all on one page. Just keep the JS as light as possible to hide/show information. Ski[ jQuery or Angular and just write a very short, very efficient script to keep the load down.

Comment: @ShaneLessard thanks for the input! I think I'll keep the JS because it's pretty light and makes everything look better. In the case of someone not having JS enabled, I just display that content on the index page (which isn't very pretty, but it's functional).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true, but most browsers doesn't load a page if they don't get an answer, so you'll need at least one local server. You can store almost everything (style, script and content) in localstorage, store as strings and eval if/when needed. Also, if local processing isn't a problem you can use AngularJS to build and rebuild the page.

Comment: My client already has a solution for hosting by modifying the firmware of the router. The site will actually be on a USB drive that's plugged into the router. So I can code this similar to any other site I make, but there are certain factors I always need to keep in mind.